# Understanding Haskell recursion in functions

Tags: haskell, recursion, functional-programming

I've been using a few resources for Haskell: Learn you a Haskell and the wikibook. However, I'm struggling to find an explanation that helps me understand recursion a bit more. I've attached a sample piece of code from the 'Learn you a Haskell' book which I partially understand.

```
maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
maximum' [] = error "maximum of empty list"  
maximum' [x] = x  
maximum' (x:xs)   
    | x > maxTail = x  
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = maximum' xs
```

I understand all of the above code until the last line 'where maxTail = maximum' xs'. What I don't understand is how the code is evaluated to return the maximum, from just calling maximum'. Or how it knows that the maximum' is the highest element of the list.

Another example:

```
reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
reverse' [] = []  
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Understand everything up until reverse' is called on the tail of the list. In other words, how does it know that reverse' means reverse the tails elements.

I would really appreciate an explanation, and apologies if it's simple, I'm new to this language.

Comment: `reverse'` doesn't mean "reverse the tail elements". `reverse' xs` means "reverse the tail elements", because `xs` is the tail elements and `reverse'` means to reverse.

Comment: Note that in the recursive case, the functions `maximum'` and `reverse'` are called on the _tail_ (i.e. anything but the first element) of the given list, e.g. `maximum' [1,2,3]` is applied recursively on the list `[2,3]`. The idea being that the maximum of a list of integers is the larger value of 1. the first list element and 2. the maximum of the rest of the list. When pattern matching on a list via `(x:xs)`, the `x` is the first list element and `xs` is the rest (the "tail").

Comment: "how does it know that reverse' means reverse the tails elements." it doesn't; but you can prove it by induction. Start with `[]` and `[a]` cases; then check out `[a,b]`, ...., then assume that it holds for the general `[a,b,...,n]` case and prove that it follows that the next case, `[a,b,...,n,m]`, is getting reversed too.

Comment: FYI: You can take a tour here: [tour] and get a quick overview of the site and all the functions/features.

Answer (score 10):

Going through the lines, line by line, so you hopefully understand it better:

```
1| maximum' :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a  
2| maximum' [] = error "maximum of empty list"  
3| maximum' [x] = x  
4| maximum' (x:xs)   
    | x > maxTail = x  
    | otherwise = maxTail  
    where maxTail = maximum' xs
```

In line 1: you say that you get a list of a's and return one element of that type. Plus the elements in that list have to be ordable, so you can put them into a order.

In line 2: you have an edge case, where you say that if you get an empty list as input, there can't be a "highest value" in that empty list, so you end the function with an error.

In line 3: you have another edge case, where you say if you get a list with 1 element, that element has to be the highest element, so you return it.

In line 4: you use pattern matching to match the first element(`x`) and the rest of the list(`xs`). Then you check if `x` is bigger than the `maxTail`, where `maxTail` the result of the function  call `maximum'` with the rest of the list `xs`.

If that `x` is bigger than `maxTail` then you return `x` and otherwise `maxTail` is bigger than `x` and you return `maxTail`.

I think an example with some numbers should also help here:

input:

```
[2, 5, 4, 13]
```

call:

```
maximum' [2, 5, 4, 13]
```

What happens:

```
maximum' (x  :  xs)
          ↓     ↓
maximum' (2:[5, 4, 13]) 
           │
           ↓                               result 13
     x > maxTail = x                         ↑
     2 > maximum' [5, 4, 13] = x  //2 > 13 = 13 ← ────┐
         │                                            │
         └  maximum' (x :  xs)                        │
                      ↓    ↓                          │
            maximum' (5:[4, 13])                      │
                       │                              │
                       ↓                              ↑
                 x > maxTail = x                      │
                 5 > maximum' [4, 13] = x  //5 > 13 = 13 ← ─────┐
                     │                                          │
                     └  maximum' (x: xs)                        │
                                  ↓  ↓                          │
                        maximum' (4:[13])                       │
                                   │                            │
                                   ↓                            ↑
                              x > maxTail = x                   │
                              4 > maximum' [13] = x  //4 > 13 = 13  ┐
                                  │                                 │
                                  └ maximum' [x] = x                ↑
                                    maximum' [13] = 13 → ───────────┘
```

---

In your second example it's pretty much the same:

```
1| reverse' :: [a] -> [a]  
2| reverse' [] = []  
3| reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

In line 1: you say that you get a list of a's and return a list of a's.

In line 2: you have an edge case, where you say if you get an empty list, the reversed list is also just empty.

In line 3: you again use pattern matching to match the first element(`x`) of the list and the tail(`xs`) of it.

Now you just use `++` to append two lists together, which is the first element of the list with the reversed tail.

And again I hope with an example it will be a bit clearer:

input:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

call:

```
reverse' [1, 2, 3]
```

What happens:

```
reverse' (x : xs)
          ↓   ↓
reverse' (1:[2, 3])
           │                               result [3, 2, 1]
           ↓                                       ↑
   (reverse' [2, 3]) ++ [1]  //[3, 2] ++ [1] = [3, 2, 1] ← ────┐
    │                                                          │
    └ reverse' (x: xs)                                         │
                ↓  ↓                                           │
      reverse' (2:[3])                                         │
                 │                                             ↑
                 ↓                                             │
         (reverse' [3]) ++ [2]  //[3] ++ [2] = [3, 2] ← ───┐ → ┘
          │                                                │
          └ reverse' (x:xs)                                │
                      ↓ ↓                                  │
            reverse' (3:[])                                │
                       │                                   ↑
                       ↓                                   │
               (reverse' []) ++ [3]  //[] ++ [3] = [3] ┐ → ┘
                │                                      ↑           
                └ reverse' [] = [] → ──────────────────┘
```

Comment: @luqui Thanks :), I tried my best so it's easy to follow and easy to understand.

Comment: Thanks for the great reply, the diagram and breakdown really helped me! :)

Answer (score 1):

## Length

```
length' [] = 0
```

Case 1: the length of an empty list is 0.

```
length' (x:xs) = 1 + length' xs
```

Case 2: the length of a list with at least one element is 1 more than the length of the tail of the list, which we find by repeating case 2 until no more elements remain, satisfying case 1.

```
length' [1, 2, 3]
=
length' (1 : (2 : (3 : [])))
=
1 + length' (2 : (3 : []))
=
1 + (1 + length' (3 : []))
=
1 + (1 + (1 + length' []))
=
1 + (1 + (1 + 0))
=
1 + (1 + 1)
=
1 + 2
=
3
```

---

## Reverse

```
reverse' [] = []
```

Case 1: if a list is empty, its reverse is also an empty list.

```
reverse' (x:xs) = reverse' xs ++ [x]
```

Case 2: if a list has at least one element, then we can pull off the first element, move it to the end, and reverse the rest in the same way—by proceeding down the list with case 2 until no elements remain, satisfying case 1.

```
reverse' [1, 2, 3]
=
reverse' (1 : (2 : (3 : [])))
=
reverse' (2 : (3 : [])) ++ [1]
=
reverse' (3 : []) ++ [2] ++ [1]
=
reverse' [] ++ [3] ++ [2] ++ [1]
=
[] ++ [3] ++ [2] ++ [1]
=
[3, 2, 1]
```

---

## Maximum

```
maximum' [x] = x
```

Case 1: if a list has only one element, that element is the maximum.

```
maximum' (x:xs)
```

Case 2: if a list has at least one element, then either…

```
    | x > maxTail = x
```

…the first one is greater than all the others, in which case it’s the maximum; or…

```
    | otherwise = maxTail
```

…it’s not, so the maximum is the greatest of all the others…

```
    where maxTail = maximum' xs
```

…which we find by proceeding down the list with case 2 until only one element remains, satisfying case 1.

I’ll rephrase the definition of `maximum'` to make it easier to show how it substitutes:

```
maximum' (x:xs) = let maxTail = maximum' xs in
    if x > maxTail then x else maxTail
```

Now:

```
maximum' [1, 3, 2]
=
maximum' (1 : (3 : (2 : [])))
=
let maxTail1 = maximum' (3 : (2 : [])) in
    if 1 > maxTail1 then 1 else maxTail1
=
let maxTail1 =
    (let maxTail2 = maximum' (2 : []) in
        if 3 > maxTail2 then 3 else maxTail2) in
    if 1 > maxTail1 then 1 else maxTail1
=
let maxTail1 =
    (let maxTail2 = 2 in
        if 3 > maxTail2 then 3 else maxTail2) in
    if 1 > maxTail1 then 1 else maxTail1
=
let maxTail1 = (if 3 > 2 then 3 else 2) in
    if 1 > maxTail1 then 1 else maxTail1
=
let maxTail1 = 3 in
    if 1 > maxTail1 then 1 else maxTail1
=
if 1 > 3 then 1 else 3
=
3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was good to see it using if and else, helped me understand it a lot better :)!